# Django: URLs contain 127.0.0.1 and not the real host-name

Tags: django, apache, gunicorn

I run Django in gunicorn (started via systemd) behind Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    <Location /relayrace/>
            ProxyPass unix:/run/gunicorn-traverse.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
            ProxyPassReverse unix:/run/gunicorn-traverse.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    </Location>
```

But the URLs (for example email created by django-allauth) use `127.0.0.1` and not the real FQDN.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting [USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#use-x-forwarded-host) and [SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) it worked:

settings.py:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

And I needed to tell Apache to provide the forwarded protocol:

```
    <Location /relayrace/>
        RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
        ProxyPass unix:/run/gunicorn-traverse.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
        ProxyPassReverse unix:/run/gunicorn-traverse.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    </Location>
```

I used [config_view](https://github.com/guettli/django-tips/blob/main/config_view.py) to debug this.